# Data partition/files permission problem

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, fstab

I can't access my files in my data partitions and I don't understand why. How can I get normal rw access to my files in my data partitions? For example, vlc gives me:

> File reading failed:
>   VLC could not open the file "/media/data01/Music/Music_Library/Jeff_Buckley/Grace/02-Grace.mpc" (Permission denied).
>   Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/data01/Music/Music_Library/Jeff_Buckley/Grace/02-Grace.mpc'. Check the log for details.

Notice that I've bind-mounted some directories of /media/data01 in fstab to my home folder. I have no problem in accessing the same file with vlc through `/home/luca/Music/Music_Library/Jeff_Buckley/Grace`. Also notice that some default software doesn't complain permission problems (e.g. Totem with the same file accessing through `/media/data01/Music/Music_Library/Jeff_Buckley/Grace/02-Grace.mpc`). Also Disk Usage Analyser (baobab) doesn't show me anything (in addition to complaining for lost+found):

[image: Disk Usage Analyser error]

Relevant parts of `/etc/fstab` follows

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=34fefb4c-5d1f-4ea8-9a73-de0aeb6bf36d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7C7D-5744  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /media/data01 was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=5bb5bb6e-5694-431f-b4f4-9b7c14fc3f56 /media/data01 ext4 defaults 0 2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0df977ea-c9ee-4215-90a3-3b2f0d562b9d none            swap    sw              0       0
# /sdb1
UUID=256fcae8-8710-45e5-93d4-e91b1d05b9fe /media/data02 ext4 defaults 0 2

# bind mounts
# ...
/media/data01/Desktop /home/luca/Desktop bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
# ...
/media/data01/Music /home/luca/Music bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
# ...
/media/data01/Workspace /home/luca/Workspace bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
```

I've checked my permissions and it seems it's all ok (apart from that Bad message for which I'm going to post another question).

```
luca@charlieBrown:/media/data01$ ls -hal /media/data01
ls: cannot access '/media/data01/System Volume Information': Bad message
total 88K
drwxr-xr-x 18 luca luca 4,0K mar 21 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K gen  5 19:03 ..
# ...
drwxr-xr-x  3 luca luca 4,0K mar 23 13:01 Desktop
# ...
drwx------  2 root root  16K gen  3 19:06 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 13 luca luca 4,0K mar 25 23:31 Music
# ...
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? System Volume Information
# ...
drwxr-xr-x 29 luca luca 4,0K mar 23 15:38 Workspace
```

and above

```
luca@charlieBrown:/media/data01$ ls -hal /media
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4,0K gen  5 19:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4,0K mar 11 23:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  18 luca luca 4,0K mar 21 11:21 data01
drwxr-xr-x  14 luca luca 4,0K mar 25 18:46 data02
drwxr-x---+  2 root root 4,0K mar 25 16:11 luca
```

My `/dev/sda` is partitioned as in the gparted screenshots.

[image: gparted sda]

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Sorry for the linked images rather than inline images but I need 10 reputations to do that, and I still have 6.

Comment: Nobody has a hint? Today I was trying to run my .sh scripts with the terminal and it says `bash: ../VidsToFrames.sh: Permission denied`, either through `/home/luca` or `/media/data01/`. I can add that I moved all my files to this new pc from an external hdd, where I had backed up stuff using `rsync -a` from my old pc. Permissions seem ok on this pc though.

Comment: The permission problem with executing scripts was due to the `user` option in `/etc/fstab` which implies `noexec`. But I can't figure out what's the reason for the issues posted in the question.